# NFC stack stops looking for new tags

Tags: android, nfc, samsung-mobile

I'm actually developping an app with an activity that has to handle a NFC tag to make the user able to use this application.

This activity is called when the app is launched and on resume.

Most of the time this works fine, but from time to time the phone (Samsung galaxy xcover 4) stops looking for new NFC tags, it doesn't even play a sound on detection.

I tried, when this bug append, to use another application from Play Store to handle the NFC tag, but nothing happened.

Here is my detection activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    if (nfcAdapter == null || !nfcAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    //method to handle your intent
    handleTag(getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    handleTag(intent);

    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
}

private void handleTag(final Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    final Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action))
    {
        try
        {
            Class isoDep = Class.forName("android.nfc.tech.IsoDep");
            Method isoDep_get = isoDep.getDeclaredMethod("get", Tag.class);

            final IsoDep techIsoDep = (IsoDep) isoDep_get.invoke(null, tag);

            if (techIsoDep != null)
            {
                // --- Tag detected
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while processing IsoPcdA object", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit :** 
I noticed this comes from the fact that, even if the screen doesn't turn black, the cpu or NFC reader goes to sleep mode, I have to lock and unlock the phone to make it work again, I'm now looking for a way to keep the cpu running all the time, what I've tried :

*Only works with Galaxy Xcover 3 (Android 6.0.1)*

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

I'm still not able to make it work on Galaxy Xcover 4 (Android 8.1)

Tried with :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

But didn't work also.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you are using Debugging mode in Android Studio and the phone lose the tag. the phone will not able to detect a tag anymore else when you turn off the NFC and turn it on again. 
I didn't read your code, because u said the same happend with another apps. 
Just try to turn the NFC off and on in your phone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works when I turn it off and on, but this happens on some other phones, with a generated APK, the same issue happens, I tried on Galaxy Xcover 3 and Xcover 4

Comment: I am using samsung devices( S8 , Tab Active2) it happend when I have used Debug Mode. 
I don't think that you can do something in your code to prevent this behavior. this is a problem in the device itself

Comment: It seems to me that the device goes in some kind of "Locked mode", as when I use the power to switch the screen off and then unlock it, I don't need to turn the NFC off and on, it works at once.
Do you know any way to prevent the device to turn in lock mode ? 
For information, the screen doesn't turn off when I cannot use NFC, maybe only CPU or NFC itself goes to lock mode